# Align button with text input and select tag bootstrap4

Tags: bootstrap-4

i can't get my button to align with the select tag , there is a little space in the bottom that i couldn't remove.
[as you can see in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DflIp.png)

This my Code :

```
<form>
    <div class="row ">
        <div class="col mt-4">
          <input type="text" name="">
        </div>
        <div class="col mt-4">
          <select></select>
        </div>
        <div class="col mt-4">
          <select></select>
        </div>

        <div class="col mt-4">
            <input type="submit" name="" value="Search" id="" class="btn btn-danger" style="border-radius: 5%;">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With bootstrap you can align items with `flex`

try this

```
<div class="col mt-4 align-self-center">
        <input type="submit" name="" value="Search" id="" class="btn btn-danger" style="border-radius: 5%;">
    </div>
```

This will center the input inside the column. The height of the button is decided by its padding and font size used.

Comment: Thaanks , it Worked :D